# Mathematical induction problem with inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have the following problem where n is a positive integer $(n >= 1)$:

Prove that $\frac{1}{2n}\le\frac{1*3*5*...*(2n-1)}{2*4*...*2n}$

I know that I must start with the basic step showing that $P(1)$ is true as follows:
$1/(2*1) = 1/2$ so $P(1)$ is true.

Now follows the induction step where I must show that "if $P(k)$ then $P(k+1)$" where 
$P(k)$ is $\frac{1}{2k}\le\frac{1*3*5*...*(2k-1)}{2*4*...*2k}$
and $P(k+1)$ is $\frac{1}{2(k+1)}\le\frac{1*3*5*...*(2k+1)}{2*4*...*2(k+1)}$

I will very much appreciate any help about how to continue.

Comment: do you __have to__ use induction ? It can be shown easily without it.

Comment: Yes, it is a homework and I am asked to use mathematical induction.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need induction: your inequality is equivalent to
$$
1\leq\frac{3\times 5\times \cdots \times (2n-1)}{2\times 4\times \cdots\times (2n-2)}=\frac{3}{2}\times\frac{5}{4}\times\cdots\times\frac{2n-1}{2n-2}\cdot
$$
The rightmost expression above is clearly no less than $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1*3*5*...*(2k-1)*(2k+1)}{2*4*...*(2k)*(2k+2)} \geq \frac{1*(2k+1)}{(2k)*(2k+2)}$$ from the induction hypothesis.

The right side is greater than $\frac{1}{(2k+2)}$ since $\frac{2k+1}{2k} > 1$.  Putting these inequalities together gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The expression that is obtained from the induction hypothesis is clear but I just do not get the idea of last comment where you say "the right side is grater than ...". I have spent some time analizing it without getting the idea.

Comment: The right side of the top inequality is equal to ((2k+1)/(2k)) * (1/(2k+2)).  This is greater than 1/(2k+2) because (2k+1)/(2k) > 1, which means you're multiplying 1/(2k+2) by a number greater than 1.

Comment: Great, I just got the idea. Thanks a lot.